# how can i show result of last record in every row in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have a situation I have to show the result of the last record in every row in Oracle SQL

### Example:-

```
**brand**  **result**  **year_month**
  nike         200        2018-01
  nike         200        2018-02
  nike         200        2018-03
  nike         300        2018-04
```

which i riquried is

```
**brand**  **result**  **year_month**
  nike         300        2018-01
  nike         300        2018-02
  nike         300        2018-03
  nike         300        2018-04
```

Based on last month record I have to propagate every month this question I have faced in BIG MNC interview

Comment: Did you understand the question correctly or expecting us to understand it first?

Comment: "Last record in every row" doesn't make sense to me. Did you mean "last record in every table"? Also - "BIG MNC"? Could you please clarify what that means? Thanks.

Comment: you are right! last record in every table.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

- `partition` makes sure that each brand gets its own result
- `order by` tells it to get `result` value that belongs to the last `year_month`

I modified input data to show that `50` isn't that obvious as the value which belongs to the last `year_month`.

---

```
SQL> with test (brand, result, year_month) as
  2    (select 'nike', 200, '2018-01' from dual union all
  3     select 'nike', 200, '2018-02' from dual union all
  4     select 'nike', 200, '2018-03' from dual union all
  5     select 'nike', 50 , '2018-04' from dual
  6    )
  7  select brand,
  8         first_value (result) over (partition by brand order by year_month desc) result,
  9         year_month
 10  from test
 11  order by year_month ;

BRAN     RESULT YEAR_MO
---- ---------- -------
nike         50 2018-01
nike         50 2018-02
nike         50 2018-03
nike         50 2018-04

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select brand,
       (select result 
        from (
            select result
            from your_table
            order by to_date(year_month,'yyyy-mm') desc
            ) 
        where rownum = 1
        ) result,
       year_month
from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT brand, Max(result) OVER(PARTITION BY brand), year_month
FROM brand;
```

The question is unclear. Is this what you're looking for?